# C# print screen predefined region

Tags: c#, printing, screen, region

I want to capture only a predefined region of the application, for example I want to print screen only the group box. I changed this.bounds to groupbox.bounds but it doesn't work. It captures other regions but not the group box. Any ideas?
The codes are:

```
// Set the bitmap object to the size of the screen
    bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    // Create a graphics object from the bitmap
    gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
    // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner
    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(this.Bounds.X, this.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, this.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

SaveFileDialog saveImageDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
saveImageDialog.Title = "Select output file:";
saveImageDialog.Filter = "JPeg Image|*.jpg|Bitmap Image|*.bmp|Gif Image|*.gif";
//saveImageDialog.FileName = printFileName;
if (saveImageDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{enter code here
    // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen
    bmpScreenshot.Save(saveImageDialog.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `DrawToBitmap`? And how is this different from [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336553/c-print-screen-active-window)?

Comment: @Code Gray: Please see the comments on my answer in that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the coordinates in the `Bounds` property are relative to its parent, but `CopyFromScreen` needs absolute coordinates.

Try using the [PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method:

```
Point p = this.PointToScreen(new Point(groupBox.Bounds.X, groupBox.Bounds.Y));
gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(p.X, p.Y, 0, 0, 
                 groupBox.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the first line must be changed to:
Point p = this.PointToScreen(new Point(groupBox2.Bounds.X, groupBox2.Bounds.Y));
In order for it to work properly. Anyway thank you very much!!