# Taking a screenshot of the desktop in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I get an error saying the encoder parameter is required on the Save() line at runtime. I have no idea what I should be putting for this parameter though. Any ideas?

```
using (Bitmap bmpScreenCapture = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height))
{
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenCapture))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                     Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                     0, 0,
                                     bmpScreenCapture.Size,
                                     CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                    bmpScreenCapture.Save(ms, bmpScreenCapture.RawFormat);   // <---- ERROR
                    byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
                    ms.Close();
                }
}
```

Comment: When you say "error," do you mean compiler or runtime?

Comment: Take a look in other posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336553/c-sharp-print-screen-active-window and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046083/save-print-screen-in-c-sharp

Comment: Neither of those are saving to a "MemoryStream" object, so I thought it was handled differently. Not sure why the crazy down votes. Someone teaches someone something and we down vote the question? Those links are not exactly the same question as mine as they are saving them to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change that line as

```
bmpScreenCapture.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
```

BTW: You can use any format that *ImageFormat* supports

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat(v=vs.110).aspx